# How to calculate re-occurrence rate of events in r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `dt`with thousands of repetitive events that may have occurred in either only one location or in both locations. How can i calculate/count the number of events that occurred only in both locations. For example in the sample `dt` below we can see `2` events (`ev2` and `ev3`) have occurred in both higher and lower location, thus the count is 2.

```
dt<-structure(list(event = c("ev1", "ev1", "ev2", "ev2", "ev2", "ev2", 
"ev2", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", 
"ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev3", "ev6", "ev6", "ev6", "ev6", "ev6", 
"ev8", "ev8", "ev8", "ev11", "ev11", "ev17"), location = c("Lower", 
"Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Lower", 
"Higher", "Higher", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", 
"Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", "Lower", 
"Lower", "Lower", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Lower", "Lower", 
"Lower")), .Names = c("event", "location"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(event = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("event", "location")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find out `event` which occur in both the `location`

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  filter(all(c("Lower", "Higher") %in% location)) %>%
  pull(event) %>% unique()

#[1] "ev2" "ev3"
```

Or if you want the count

```
dt %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  filter(all(c("Lower", "Higher") %in% location)) %>%
  pull(event) %>% n_distinct()
#[1] 2
```

---

In base R, we can use `aggregate`

```
df1 <- aggregate(location~event, dt, function(x) all(c("Lower", "Higher") %in% x))

df1$event[df1$location]
#[1] "ev2" "ev3"

length(df1$event[df1$location])
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ronak's method is much more robust, lol, but you can also just remove the rows where both are duplicated, and then look for duplicates in the event column:

```
temp_df <- dt[!duplicated(dt[c("event","location")]),]
sum(duplicated(temp_df$event))
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also paste unique rows together and count the duplicated prefixes using `regexpr`.

```
sum(table(regmatches(v <- unique(apply(dt, 1, paste, collapse="")), regexpr("\\d+", v))) > 1)
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nrow(setDT(dt)[, .GRP[sum(c("Lower", "Higher") %in% location) == 2], event])
#[1] 2
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    filter(location %in% c("Lower", "Higher")) %>% 
    distinct %>% 
    count(event) %>% 
    filter(n == 2) %>% 
    nrow
#[1] 2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sum(rowSums(table(unique(dt))) == 2)
#[1] 2
```